# Automatically joining tables without breaking default behaviour in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

The situation is as follows: I've got 2 models: 'Action' and 'User'. These models refer to the tables 'actions' and 'users', respectively.

My action table contains a column `user_id`. At this moment, I need an overview of all actions, and the users to which they are assigned to. When i use `$action->fetchAll()`, I only have the user ID, so I want to be able to join the data from the user model, preferably without making a call to `findDependentRowset()`.

I thought about creating custom `fetchAll()`, `fetchRow()` and `find()` methods in my model, but this would break default behaviour.

What is the best way to solve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with Zend_Db_Table_Row::findDependentRowset()?

Comment: One objection to findDependentRowset() and findParentRow() is that it's less efficient to lazy-load related rows one at a time than to query both tables with a JOIN when you know from the start that you need all the related rows.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I designed and implemented the table-relationships feature in Zend Framework.

My first comment is that you wouldn't use `findDependentRowset()` anyway -- you'd use `findParentRow()` if the Action has a foreign key reference to User.

```
$actionTable = new Action();
$actionRowset = $actionTable->fetchAll();
foreach ($actionRowset as $actionRow) {
  $userRow = $actionRow->findParentRow('User');
}
```

**Edit:**  In the loop, you now have an $actionRow and a $userRow object.  You can write changes back to the database through either object by changing object fields and calling `save()` on the object.

You can also use the Zend_Db_Table_Select class (which was implemented after I left the project) to retrieve a Rowset based on a join between Action and User.

```
$actionTable = new Action();
$actionQuery = $actionTable->select()
  ->setIntegrityCheck(false) // allows joins
  ->from($actionTable)
  ->join('user', 'user.id = action.user_id');
$joinedRowset = $actionTable->fetchAll($actionQuery);
foreach ($joinedRowset as $joinedRow) {
  print_r($joinedRow->toArray());
}
```

Note that such a Rowset based on a join query is read-only.  You cannot set field values in the Row objects and call `save()` to post changes back to the database.

**Edit:** There is no way to make an arbitrary joined result set writable.  Consider a simple example based on the joined result set above:

```
action_id  action_type  user_id  user_name
   1          Buy          1       Bill
   2          Sell         1       Bill
   3          Buy          2       Aron
   4          Sell         2       Aron
```

Next for the row with action_id=1, I change one of the fields that came from the User object:

```
$joinedRow->user_name = 'William';
$joinedRow->save();
```

Questions:  when I view the next row with action_id=2, should I see 'Bill' or 'William'?  If 'William', does this mean that saving row 1 has to automatically update 'Bill' to 'William' in all other rows in this result set?  Or does it mean that `save()` automatically re-runs the SQL query to get a refreshed result set from the database?  What if the query is time-consuming?

Also consider the object-oriented design.  Each Row is a separate object.  Is it appropriate that calling `save()` on one object has the side effect of changing values in a separate object (even if they are part of the same collection of objects)?  That seems like a form of [Content Coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_science)) to me.

The example above is a relatively simple query, but much more complex queries are also permitted.  Zend_Db cannot analyze queries with the intention to tell writable results from read-only results.  That's also why MySQL views are not updateable.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation clarifies the situation; I'll simply go with a custom method that returns a read-only object.

Comment: +1 and Thanks, I was looking for something like this too. Would be cool if ZF had something like RoR's `find(:all, :includes)` though

Comment: Check out http://www.doctrine-project.org/ for an alternative ORM.  ZF's Db component has pretty much stagnated.  But ZF is so loosely coupled, it's really easy to use a different Db component.

Answer (score 2):

You could always make a view in your database that does the join for you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VwAction AS
SELECT [columns]
  FROM action
  LEFT JOIN user
    ON user.id = action.user_id
```

Then just use

```
$vwAction->fetchAll();
```

Just remember that views in MySQL are read-only (assuming this is MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

isn't creating a view sql table a good solution to make joint ?
and after a simple table class to access it

I would think it's better if your logic is in sql than in php