# Outer Join using Propel 1.2?

Tags: php, symfony1, propel, outer-join

I'm trying to do an Outer Join in Symfony. Here's the bit of code that seems like it would work if Criteria supported OUTER_JOIN:

```
$user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser();
$petCriteria = new Criteria();
$petCriteria->add(PetInfoPeer::ACCOUNT_ID, $user->getProfile()->getAccountId());
$petCriteria->add(LostPetPeer::PET_INFO_ID, Criteria::ISNULL);
$petCriteria->addJoin(LostPetPeer::PET_INFO_ID, PetInfoPeer::PET_INFO_ID, Criteria::OUTER_JOIN);
```

Am I missing something? Does Propel 1.3 support it? I've searched everywhere and have only found pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using criteria. You'd have to write and run the SQL, then build the models, yourself.

[Here's a good example of that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246400/symfony-app-how-to-add-calculated-fields-to-propel-objects#247259), found on this site.

Comment: I've confirmed this via IRC #symfony.